# How do I send multiple checked checkboxes to the database?

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working on arrays and I want to send multiple checked checkboxes to the database and I just can't seem to make it work.

This is for my school project which is creating a system, I'm building a website with a reservation and ordering system, here's the process, when you want to order a specific type of food you need to check the checkboxes, of course some users would order more so they have to check multiple checkboxes, I tried typing the codes I know and it still doesn't work.

Menu form Code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $dish=$_POST["dish"];
  $newvalues= implode(",", $dish);
  $checkboxClass=new checkboxClass();
  echo $checkboxClass->addtoDatabase($newvalues);
}
?>
<!--Food Gallery -->
<form method="POST" action="success.php">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column Appetizers">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="images/APPETIZER/Chasyu.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <h4><input type="checkbox" id="dish" name="dish[]" value="Chasyu">CHASYU</h4>
      <p>P100</p>
      <br>
  <select name ="orderselect[]" id="orderselect" class="form">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="column Appetizers">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="images/APPETIZER/CORN BUTTER.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <h4><input type="checkbox" id="dish" name="dish[]" value="CornButter">CORN BUTTER</h4>
      <p>P80</p>
      <br>
  <select name ="orderselect[]" id="orderselect" class="form">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Success page code:

```
<?php

require_once './connectionClass.php';
class checkboxClass extends connectionClass{
    public function addtoDatabase($value){
        $insert ="Insert into reserveform (customer_order) values ('$value')";
        $result=$this->query($insert)or die($this->error);
        if($result){
            echo  "<h1>Ordering Success</h1>";
        }
        else{
            echo  "<h1>Not Updated</h1>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.